# Crop image, save it

Tags: php, gd

```
    $filename = '/home/hey/Desktop/images/oldImage.jpg';
    $percent = 0.5;

    // Get new dimensions
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
    $new_width = $width * $percent;
    $new_height = $height * $percent;

    // Resample
    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
    file_put_contents("/home/hey/Desktop/images/oldImage.jpg", imagejpeg($image_p));
```

I just want to crop oldImage a little bit and save it again. What's wrong? Thanks.

**edit: Image is just not created. It creates empty image.**

Comment: Why don't you tell us what's wrong, and maybe then we can help you fix it. Is the image not created? Is the image weird looking? Does it turn into a photo of a cat? What errors do you get?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I will update now.

Comment: Have you read the manual on `imagejpeg()`? It'll make things clearer. http://php.net/imagejpeg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use the simpler:

```
// Save the image as 'simpletext.jpg'
imagejpeg($image_p, 'simpletext.jpg');
```

Comment: This is not only simpler, it is also the only way to do this :)